# How can I force update the Python locals() dictionary of a different stack frame?

Tags: python, python-internals, inspect, stack-frame, locals

In Python 2 (not sure about 3), the locals dictionary only gets updated when you actually call locals(). So e.g.

```
l=locals()
x=2
l['x']
```

fails because `l` doesn't have the key "x" in it, but

```
l=locals()
x=2
locals()
l['x']
```

returns 2.

I'm looking for a way to force an update of the locals dictionary, but the trick is that I'm in a different stack frame. So e.g. I'm looking to do

```
l=locals()
x=2
force_update()
l['x']
```

and I need to write the `force_update()` function. I know that from said function I can get the parent frame via `inspect.currentframe().f_back`, and even the parent (non-updated) locals via `inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals`, but how can I force an update?

If this seems convoluted, my main goal is to write a function which is shorthand for `"{some} string".format(**dict(globals(),**locals()))` so I don't have to type that out each time, and can instead do `fmt("{some} string")`. Doing so I run into the issue above.

*Edit*: With Martjin answer below, below is essentially the solution I was looking for. One could play around with exactly how they get the stack frame of the callee, here I do it via `partial`.

```
from functools import partial
from inspect import currentframe

fmt = partial(lambda s,f: s.format(**dict(globals(),**f.f_locals)),f=currentframe())
x=2
print fmt("{x}") #prints "2"
```

Comment: In your editor you could define a shortcut, snippet, or whatever the editor calls it to expand to `.format(**dict(globals(),**locals()))`. A lot of editors support something like this.

Comment: Why are you using `"{some} string".format(**dict(globals(),**locals()))` so many times in your code? Does your format string really need access to every variable in the local and global namespaces?

Comment: If you can get the parent frame (see also `sys._getframe(1)`) then why do you need `globals()` and `locals()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply *accessing `f_locals` on a frame object* triggers the copy, so using `inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals` *is enough*.

See the [`frame_getlocals()` function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.1/Objects/frameobject.c#l21) in the `frameobject.c` implementation:

```c
static PyObject *
frame_getlocals(PyFrameObject *f, void *closure)
{
    PyFrame_FastToLocals(f);
    Py_INCREF(f->f_locals);
    return f->f_locals;
}
```

`PyFrame_FastToLocals` is the function used to copy the data from the interal array tracking locals values to a dictionary. `frame_getlocals` is used to implement the `frame.f_locals` descriptor (a property); see the [`frame_getsetlist` definition](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.1/Objects/frameobject.c#l366).

The `PyFrame_FastToLocalsWithError` function used above is *exactly* what `locals()` uses to produce the same dictionary (by [wrapping](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.1/Python/bltinmodule.c#l1465) the [`PyEval_GetLocals` function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.1/Python/ceval.c#l4437)).

Comment: Aha! Thanks. I managed to find `currentframe().f_locals` but not realize that it exactly forces the update I was looking for.

Comment: Yes - jus beware that the opposite does not happen - there is no way to update the fast variables by changing the values in the locals.

Comment: @CharlieParker: I linked to the Python 3 source code in my answer; yes, it works in Python 3.

Comment: @MartijnPieters wait si ur actually able to update locals and have things work? I've been looking for something like this with no luck at all. Why does ur approach work while others fail?

Comment: @CharlieParker: you can't add or update locals through the `locals()` dictionary (not via the `locals()` return value nor the `f_locals` reference), no.

Comment: @MartijnPieters just out of curiosity, why is that not possible (even with your solution)?

Comment: @CharlieParker: see [Change the value of a local variable where variable name will be expressed as a string](//stackoverflow.com/a/32440576), Python heavily optimises the locals namespace in functions.